# How to reload data in existing dataTable()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have table that is already displayed on the screen. If user added new row or edit existing row then new set of data will be returned with the ajax. Once data is retrieved I want to clear the existing records from `tbody` and refresh/reload `dataTable` . Here is example of my code:

```js
var statusData = {
  479664: {
    "author": "JH2423",
    "up_to": "09/30/2017",
    "status": "Closed",
    "as_of": "06/12/2017",
    "date": "06/23/2017",
    "current": false,
    "reason": "Slow",
    "status_id": "479664"
  },
  479665: {
    "author": "KK2342",
    "up_to": "09/30/2017",
    "status": "Approved",
    "as_of": "06/12/2017",
    "date": "06/23/2017",
    "current": false,
    "reason": "Close",
    "status_id": "479664"
  },
  479666: {
    "author": "DD7822",
    "up_to": "09/30/2017",
    "status": "Close",
    "as_of": "06/12/2017",
    "date": "06/23/2017",
    "current": false,
    "reason": "Process",
    "status_id": "479666"
  },
  479667: {
    "author": "YU8343",
    "up_to": "09/30/2017",
    "status": "Declined",
    "as_of": "06/12/2017",
    "date": "06/23/2017",
    "current": false,
    "reason": "Warrning",
    "status_id": "479667"
  },
  479668: {
    "author": "MMSD3",
    "up_to": "09/30/2017",
    "status": "Participating",
    "as_of": "06/12/2017",
    "date": "06/23/2017",
    "current": false,
    "reason": "Approved",
    "status_id": "479668"
  }
};

buildDataTable('tbl-status', false, 2, false, true, true, []);

function buildDataTable(tblID, lengthChange, pageLen, searchBar, infoSection, pagingInfo, arrOrder) {
  var table = $("#" + tblID),
    arrSort = [];

  if (arrOrder.length) {
    arrSort.push(arrOrder); // arrOrder example: [1, "desc"] or [4, "asc"]. First element is column (first col starts from 0) and second is order by direction.
  }

  $(table).DataTable({
    lengthChange: lengthChange,
    pageLength: pageLen,
    lengthMenu: [
      [10, 15, 20, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 15, 20, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    order: arrSort,
    searching: searchBar,
    info: infoSection,
    paging: pagingInfo
  });
}

$("#load").on("click", function() {
  var container = $("#status-container"), // Clear out existing table.
    table = $("<table>").addClass("table").prop("id", "tbl-status"),
    thead = $("<thead><tr><th>Reason</th><th>As Of</th><th>Up To</th><th>Author</th><th>Date</th><th>Status</th><th class='text-center'>Status</th></tr></thead>"),
    tbody = $("<tbody>");

  if ($.isEmptyObject(statusData)) {
    var tr = $('<tr><td colspan="7">No records were found.</td></tr>');
    tbody.append(tr);
  } else {
    for (key in statusData) {
      var btnName = statusData[key].current == true ? "Change" : "Edit";
      var tr = $('<tr>');
      tbody.append(tr);
      tr.append($('<td>').text(statusData[key].reason));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(statusData[key].as_of));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(statusData[key].up_to));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(statusData[key].author));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(statusData[key].date));
      tr.append($('<td>').text(statusData[key].status));
      tr.append($('<td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm status-edit" data-recid="' + statusData[key].status_id + '" data-current="' + statusData[key].current + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' + btnName + '</button></td>'));
    }
  }
  
  $("#tbl-agency-status").remove(); // Remove existing table.
  table.append([thead, tbody]);
  container.append(table);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="load" id="load">Load New Data</button>
<div class="card mt-4">
  <div class="card-header card-bg-custom">
    <h5 class="text-center">Status</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="status-container">
      <table class="table" id="tbl-status">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Reason</th>
            <th>As Of</th>
            <th>Up To</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th class="text-center">Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Failure</td>
            <td>09/11/2019</td>
            <td>10/31/2019</td>
            <td>System</td>
            <td>10/01/2019</td>
            <td>Conditional</td>
            <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm status-edit" data-recid="505552" data-current="true"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Change</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Initial</td>
            <td>06/12/2017</td>
            <td>09/30/2017</td>
            <td>MM434</td>
            <td>06/23/2017</td>
            <td>Participating</td>
            <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm status-edit" data-recid="479664" data-current="false"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Reporting</td>
            <td>07/11/2019</td>
            <td>08/31/2019</td>
            <td>System</td>
            <td>10/01/2019</td>
            <td>Testing</td>
            <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm status-edit" data-recid="505551" data-current="true"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason current data is not removed. I would like to remove all existing data and reload new data in the table. If anyone have suggestion please let me know.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() look at the documentation.

Comment: @NawedKhan I'm not 100% sure that is exactly what I need. If you look at my example my data is loaded in the JS object. Maybe I'm not understanding exactly your point.

Comment: Can you put your JS object in a separate file, then you can load it via Ajax and use the reload function that @NawedKhan mentioned?

Comment: Where does *statusData* come from, or where would it come from when you click the Load New Data button? I could be missing something, but if *statusData* is a hard coded var like in your example, how are you expecting it to show new row info?

Comment: @Aaron The `statusData` is global js object that I use as a storage. When user clicks on the Load New Data ajax will retrieve the data from the server and populate `statusData` object. This way data is always available on the front end in case user need to pull some information or change the data.  The idea is instead of replacing single row just reload the data after ajax call is completed.

Comment: Ok, there are much easier built-in ways to handle all of these functionality aspects with datatables. I can't determine yet if there is a specific reason why you are going about it this way. With the current approach you are going to have to re-invent a lot of the wheel. I'll post answer below with example of different approach.

Comment: simple answer is don't load data from html or object.  it's slower and you stated that you'd like to load data from ajax anyway so just use ajax data source from the beginning and then use `ajax.reload()`.  problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script> //I usually put the script section at the end of head tag

var table_1; //declare your table var here and initialize as a datatable inside document ready below.

$(document).ready(function() {

  table_1 = $('#table_1').DataTable( {
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: {
        url: "/get-data",  //path where json data will be served from. ex: get-data.php or my-data.json
        type: "POST"  //use POST to not have to deal with url encoding various characters
    },      
    serverSide: true,
    searchDelay: 2000,  // use this to throttle ajax requests when typing in search input 
    processing: true, // optional visual indicator that a search has been sent to backend
    lengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ], // define per page limits. first value will be the default
    buttons: [
        "pageLength" // per page drop down button. i usually override/extend the default button
    ],      
    columns: [ // column definitions of json data fields
      { data: "status_id", title: "ID", width: "1%" },  // width:1% makes col width as small as possible
      { data: "status", title: "Status(hidden)", visible:false }, //visible:false hides column but allows you access to field data
      { data: "reason", title: "Reason and Status", render: function ( data, type, row ) { //render allows combining of fields into single column
        return data + ' <small>('+row.status+')</small>'; // data will be reason value. row.status is how you reference status value
      } },
      { data: "current", title: "Current", searchable:false }, //searchable: false set this field to not be used in search
      { data: null, title: "Button", render: function ( data, type, row ) { // use data:null if you need to render stuff in a column that does not necessarily need to be tied to a specific data value
        if(row.current){
          return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm status-edit" data-recid="'+ row.status_id +'" data-current="true"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Change</button>';
        }
        else{
          return '<button>Different Button</button>';
        }
      } },
    ],
    rowId: 'status_id' //sets the tr row id to the value in this column. useful for DOM and other manipulation later
  } );
}

</script>

<table id="table_1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" style="width:100%"></table>

<!-- If you define the title attributes in json column definitions above 
then you don't need to create html table headers/footers. 
Just an empty table tag will do. -->
```

Your ajax url will need to return data as JSON format with an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "author": "KK2342",
    "up_to": "09/30/2017",
    "status": "Approved",
    "as_of": "06/12/2017",
    "date": "06/23/2017",
    "current": false,
    "reason": "Close",
    "status_id": "479664"
  },
  {
    "author": "DD7822",
    "up_to": "09/30/2017",
    "status": "Close",
    "as_of": "06/12/2017",
    "date": "06/23/2017",
    "current": false,
    "reason": "Process",
    "status_id": "479666"
  }
]
```

To get started create a file named *testing.json* with the above contents. Then replace table_1 ajax-url from above example to '/your_folder_path/testing.json'. This datatable should now load.

To get access to the data all you need to do is call:

```
table_1.data(); // datatables object
//OR
table_1.data().toArray(); // a simple array of objects with each rows data you can loop through
```

Docs on manipulating data for every row can be found here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()

After data has been modified you can table_1.draw() or table_1.reload() as @NawedKahn suggested - depending on your use case.

***Tons of useful functionality can be found in Docs below***

Everything you can *do* with datatables objects:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/

All datatables options:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/

*Browse through these links before you try to build any sort of functionality, it probably already exists.*